# Why are unions which have members with differing access control not standard-layout?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, unions, standard-layout

§9.0

> 7. A class S is a standard-layout class if it:
>
> (7.3)
>   has the same access control (Clause
>   11
>   ) for all non-static data members,
>
> 8
>   A
>   standard-layout struct
>   is a standard-layout class defined with the
>   class-key
>   struct
>   or the
>   class-key
>   class
>   .
>   A
>   standard-layout union
>   is a standard-layout class defined with the
>   class-key
>   union
>   .

AFAICT, §9.0.7.3 exists because of §9.2.13

> 13
>   Nonstatic data members of a (non-union) class with the same access control (Clause
>   11
>   ) are allocated so
>   that later members have higher addresses within a class object. **The order of allocation of non-static data
>   members with different access control is unspecified** (Clause
>   11
>   ). Implementation alignment requirements
>   might cause two adjacent members not to be allocated immediately after each other; so might requirements
>   for space for managing virtual functions (
>   10.3
>   ) and virtual base classes (
>   10.1
>   ).

However, this does not seem to apply to unions, as all (non-static data) members of a union have the same address.  Is this a defect in the standard?  Or is there some compelling reason why that I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the benefit of allowing multiple access specifiers in the `union` case were not outweighed by the cost of the inconsistency and additional words introduced.